# Html5 desktop webapp options besides titanium

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, air, titanium

I'm making a html5 game and while I'd like to be able to publish the game to a web platform like chrome store, the game plays closer to a traditional desktop game. So I'd like to be able to make it for the desktop too and take advantage of desktop app stores as well.

Air would have been ideal except that they dropped support for linux which is my main platform. I liked Titanium but it doesn't have support for html5 audio yet and installing it onto linux can be tricky sometimes. I researched Phonegap but it's targeted toward mobile and not desktop. **Is there a simple platform out there that'll just let me wrap my app in a webkit frame or something?**

**All I want to do is have my game run in a browser frame**, I don't need any crazy features like a server because all it is is html and javascript, nothing server side. With all the cool things out there like Titanium and phonegap I'm positive there has to be something simple like this out there.

Thanks a lot

Comment: XULRunner is a cross-platform toolkit made by Mozilla and powers Firefox's UI. It should work.

Comment: You need to put this as an answer for others, it literally took me a few hours to set up right once I realized which version of xulrunner was needed and found the documents to set everything up. Running perfect and looks just like a desktop app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender was right. XULrunner was a great platform. I literally had my webapp up and running within a few hours of going through tutorials and docs. Works great, I'd recommend it to anyone else with this need at least until someone makes something a bit more documented.

Here's a good starter tutorial:
http://www.kodewerx.org/wiki/A_Brief_Introduction_To_XULRunner:_Part_1

And a hint, no need to download XULrunner while developing, firefox has a command line argument for it. Just

```
$ firefox -app /path/to/application.ini
```

And it'll run. So if you have firefox, you have XULrunner. And it'll work at least until release.

Comment: Sounds good :) Would you mind sharing a skeleton web app for displaying web apps ina XULRunner window? And how you packaged the app for the different platforms, solved application updates, etc? The packaging section on http://www.kodewerx.org/wiki/A_Brief_Introduction_To_XULRunner:_Part_2#Packaging is rather vague. TideSDK (formerly Titanium) has this as part of the framework.

Comment: Wow this is pretty old but I'll give you a hint if I can. Basically you just put in a <browser> tag with the path to your webapp in the zip file and that's literally it. The browser window is basically firefox, so if your webapp works on firefox that's all you need. 

There's a lot more too, you can make a whole gui with html and javascript and control the window and everything. It's one of the easiest things I've used EVER. I can't believe we don't hear more about XULrunner because it is amazing.

I wish I still has the old webapp I made to give you an example but I don't have it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for getting back :) In the meantime, I had to wip up a skeleton app myself, all available on https://github.com/neam/webapp-xul-wrapper with packaging scripts for generating installers and update packages adapted from Zotero standalone. I can't say it was the easiest to use ever, but at least it works (as opposed to [some other solutions](http://blog.neamlabs.com/post/36584972328/2012-11-26-web-app-cross-platform-desktop-distribution)), so thanks for getting me onto the right track! :)